# Resetting multi index for a pivot_table to get single line index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe in the following format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['1-Jul', '2-Jul', '3-Jul', '1-Jul', '2-Jul', '3-Jul'], 'b':[1,1,1,2,2,2], 'c':[3,1,2,4,3,2]})
```

I need the following dataframe:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'a':['1-Jul', '2-Jul', '3-Jul'], 1:[3, 1, 2], 2:[4,3,2]}).
```

I have tried the following:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index = ['a'], columns = ['b'], values = ['c'])
df_new = df.reset_index()
```

but it doesn't give me the required result. I have tried variations of this to no avail. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about `df_new = df.pivot_table(index = 'a', columns = 'b', values = 'c').reset_index()`?

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain why my code wasn't working? It looks very similar to yours. Does passing in lists as arguments change stuff?

Comment: when you pass `values=['c']` to `pivot_table`, you are trying to pivot a **list** of columns. So the return dataframe will have double-indexed columns, since you need one extra level to identify which column the data comes from, so it could work if you pass `values=['c','d']`

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
df2 = df.groupby('a')['c'].agg(['first','last']).reset_index()
cols_ = df['b'].unique().tolist()
cols_.insert(0,df.columns[0])
df2.columns = cols_
df2
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I just used Quang Hoang's solution above as it was a one-liner.